# Taking list and turning into tuples for dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

`[['0', '0', '254', '0', 'R'], ['0', '97', '0', '65', 'R'], ['0', '98', '0', '66', 'R'], []]`

in this format `[a,b,c,d,e]`

what I am trying to do is make a dictionary such that `(a,b) : (c,d,e)`

```
rules = dict(((a, b), (c, d, e)) 
            for (a, b, c, d, e) in rules)
```

The error I am getting is this:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 0)

I am guessing my problem is formatting the input string as it is not reading it as a tuple.

What I would like to do is read in the list as a tuple and extract the 5 values in each set as the values a,b,c,d,e for the dictionary

Comment: Your main issue is the empty `[]` at the end of your 2D list

Comment: Your last item in the list is empty list. There is nothing to unpack there. You should either handle that gracefully, or clean it up first.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the size is 5?

```
l = [
    ['0', '0', '254', '0', 'R'], 
    ['0', '97', '0', '65', 'R'], 
    ['0', '98', '0', '66', 'R'], 
    []
]

out = {(x[0],x[1]):(x[2],x[3],x[4]) for x in l if len(x) == 5} # or just if x
print(out)
```

---

**or** thanks to @Jon Clements

```
out = {tuple(x[:2]):x[2:] for x in l if x}
```

Returns:

```
{('0', '0'): ('254', '0', 'R'), 
 ('0', '97'): ('0', '65', 'R'), 
 ('0', '98'): ('0', '66', 'R')}
```

Comment: Or `{x[:2]: x[2:] for x in l}`

Comment: Did you include your `if x` check at the end?

Comment: Oh yes... sorry - I glanced over the fact the source data was actually lists... thought they were tuples - ignore me :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = [['0', '0', '254', '0', 'R'], ['0', '97', '0', '65', 'R'], ['0', '98', '0', '66', 'R'], []]
result = {(a, b): (c, d, e) for a, b, c, d, e in filter(None, data)}
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{('0', '97'): ('0', '65', 'R'), ('0', '98'): ('0', '66', 'R'), ('0', '0'): ('254', '0', 'R')}
```

Or more similar to your code:

```
rules = [['0', '0', '254', '0', 'R'], ['0', '97', '0', '65', 'R'], ['0', '98', '0', '66', 'R'], []]
result = dict(((a, b), (c, d, e)) for a, b, c, d, e in filter(None, rules))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{('0', '0'): ('254', '0', 'R'), ('0', '98'): ('0', '66', 'R'), ('0', '97'): ('0', '65', 'R')}
```